# How to count the number of columns in json file ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json file in my website project,  like this:

```
 [
 {
"id": "1",
"name": "ramesh",
"phone": "12345",
"salary": "50000"
},

{
"id": "2",
"name": "suresh",
"phone": "123456",
"salary": "60000"
 },

 {
"id": "3",
"name": "mahesh",
"phone": "123457",
"salary": "70000"
}
]
```

Here it is the sample data, It has 4 columns but i don't know that my json data which i will get, will have how many number of columns.

I just want to know the number of columns I have in json file. Currently i am creating table like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonitems = [];
        $.getJSON("json.json", function (data) {
           var employee_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                employee_data += '<tr>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.salary + '</td>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.phone + '</td>';
                employee_data += '</tr>';

            });
            $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);

        });
    });
```

I have tried toArray(), data[0].columns etc, but not getting this. Please let me know the way to count the columns?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can use `Object.keys(obj).length;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Object.keys() in order to get the number of keys of an object.
You have a JSON with an array of objects, each object has 4 properties. I understand you are reporting the object into a table, so you need to know how many columns you will have, but in case of objects the term properties or keys is more appropriate

```js
var a = [
 {
"id": "1",
"name": "ramesh",
"phone": "12345",
"salary": "50000"
},

{
"id": "2",
"name": "suresh",
"phone": "123456",
"salary": "60000"
 },

 {
"id": "3",
"name": "mahesh",
"phone": "123457",
"salary": "70000"
}
];

console.log(Object.keys(a[0]).length);
```

So in your case:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonitems = [];
        $.getJSON("json.json", function (data) {
           var employee_data = '';
            // number of keys of the current object
            console.log(Object.keys(data[0]));
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                employee_data += '<tr>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.salary + '</td>';
                employee_data += '<td>' + value.phone + '</td>';
                employee_data += '</tr>';

            });
            $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);

        });
    });
```

In order to cycle inside the data you can do it without using jQuery and just using plain JS in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var jsonitems = [];
            $.getJSON("json.json", function (data) {
               var employee_data = '';
                // number of keys of the current object
                console.log(Object.keys(data[0]));
                data.forEach((employee) => {
                    employee_data += '<tr>';
                    employee_data += '<td>' + employee.id + '</td>';
                    employee_data += '<td>' + employee.name + '</td>';
                    employee_data += '<td>' + employee.salary + '</td>';
                    employee_data += '<td>' + employee.phone + '</td>';
                    employee_data += '</tr>';

                });
                $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);

            });
        });
```

Comment: but *"columns"* is very appropriate term for table being produced

Comment: @charlietfl yeah totally correct, but here his sentence: "Here it is the sample data, It has 4 columns " and his title: "How to count the number of columns in json file ?

"

Comment: thanks @quirimmo but when i added "var a=" to my json file, it shows error - unexpected character sequence.

Comment: Hi @Mogli, you don't need to use var a in front of your JSON, I was just creating a working example here. You can try this code inside your most inner function: `console.log(Object.keys(value));` it should print 4 for each object. Updating the answer with the code there, it's easier to read

Comment: yes now it is working but it's giving me all the column names, not the number of total column, but (Object.keys(value).length) is working fine. But still it is written in .each so it will be repeated every time, is there any more efficient way or place to write this line so that it may run only once !!

Comment: sure, move it before the loop, updating the answer

Comment: just edited, in this way you will have before the loop the number of properties inside the first object of your json array

Comment: @quirimmo can u tell me if i need to access the values what do i need to write?

Comment: in jquery i am able to access but what if i need to access it using javascript only using for loop ?

Comment: @Mogli updating the answer here is awful to write code :)

Comment: what if  i don't know the column names like id, name etc. then how to write this value.id or value.name ??

Comment: You can access it with brackets notation (array's style) myobj[0] gets your first property